# Transform Oddity

Tags: html, xml, excel, xslt, openxml

I don't understand why some output spans have their style attribute set to an empty string.

Also, how can this be simplified to remove the loops and conditionals?

I have struggled with this for days. I appreciate any help offered. I know the xlst is a long way from ideal. I am just learning.

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
                xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
                xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"
                version="1.0">



    <xsl:output method="html"/>


    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:for-each select="ss:Workbook/ss:Worksheet/ss:Table/ss:Row">
            <xsl:element name="tr">
                <xsl:for-each select="ss:Cell">
                    <xsl:element name="td">

                        <xsl:if test="not(ss:Data/*)"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:if>                         
                        <xsl:for-each select="ss:Data/*">

                            <xsl:call-template name="recursive-template">
                                <xsl:with-param name="myElement" select="."/>
                            </xsl:call-template>  

                        </xsl:for-each>

                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>            

    </xsl:template>                  


    <xsl:template name="recursive-template">
        <xsl:param name="myElement" />
        <xsl:if test="name($myElement)='Font'">
            <xsl:element name="span">                                                                          
                <xsl:attribute name="style">
                    <xsl:if test="@html:Color">color:<xsl:value-of select="@html:Color"/>; </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="@html:Size">font-size:<xsl:value-of select="@html:Size"/>pt; </xsl:if>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$myElement/*">
                        <xsl:call-template name="recursive-template">
                            <xsl:with-param name="myElement" select="$myElement/*"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$myElement"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>                  
            </xsl:element>                               
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="name($myElement)!='Font'">
            <xsl:element name="{lower-case(name($myElement))}">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$myElement/*">
                        <xsl:call-template name="recursive-template">
                            <xsl:with-param name="myElement" select="$myElement/*"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$myElement"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>            
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>    


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUTPUT**

The below output is correct with the exception of the few spans with empty style attributes. Note that the CSS must be inline so that the HTML can be emailed and still present properly in GMail.

```
<tr>
   <td>ID</td>
   <td>Date</td>
   <td>Quantity</td>
   <td>Customer</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>754</td>
   <td>2016-11-15T00:00:00.000</td>
   <td>95</td>
   <td><s><span style="">A</span></s><span style="color:#000000; ">jax</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>432</td>
   <td>2016-11-03T00:00:00.000</td>
   <td>14</td>
   <td><span style="color:#000000; ">Kr</span><i><span style="">oo</span></i><span style="color:#000000; ">n</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>322</td>
   <td>2016-11-01T00:00:00.000</td>
   <td>52</td>
   <td><b><s><span style="">S</span></s></b><span style="color:#000000; ">hou</span><span style="color:#FF0000; ">t</span><span style="color:#000000; ">er K</span><span style="color:#C65911; ">res</span><span style="color:#000000; ">t</span></td>
</tr>
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s151">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="2"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"
    ss:Bold="1"/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s152">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:Indent="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="2"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="2"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"
    ss:Bold="1"/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s153">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="2"/>
   </Borders>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s154">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="d\-mmm"/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s155">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s156">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:Indent="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="2"/>
   </Borders>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s161">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="2"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="2"/>
   </Borders>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s162">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="2"/>
   </Borders>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="d\-mmm"/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s163">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="2"/>
   </Borders>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s164">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:Indent="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="2"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="2"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
   </Borders>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s165">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Center"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="2"/>
   </Borders>
   <Interior ss:Color="#92D050" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s166">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Center"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#92D050" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="d\-mmm"/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s167">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Center"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#92D050" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s170">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="2"
     ss:Color="#FF0000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="2"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="2"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"
    ss:Bold="1"/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s185">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Center" ss:Indent="2"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="2"/>
   </Borders>
   <Interior ss:Color="#92D050" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
  </Style>
 </Styles>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet4">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="4" ss:ExpandedRowCount="4"
   ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
   <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="54.75"/>
   <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="122.25"/>
   <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="54.75"/>
   <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="101.25"/>
   <Row ss:Height="15.75">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s170"><Data ss:Type="String">ID</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s151"><Data ss:Type="String">Date</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s151"><Data ss:Type="String">Quantity</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s152"><Data ss:Type="String">Customer</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s153"><Data ss:Type="Number">754</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s154"><Data ss:Type="DateTime">2016-11-15T00:00:00.000</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s155"><Data ss:Type="Number">95</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s156"><ss:Data ss:Type="String"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><S><Font html:Color="#000000">A</Font></S><Font
       html:Color="#000000">jax</Font></ss:Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="27">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s165"><Data ss:Type="Number">432</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s166"><Data ss:Type="DateTime">2016-11-03T00:00:00.000</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s167"><Data ss:Type="Number">14</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s185"><ss:Data ss:Type="String"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><Font html:Color="#000000">Kr</Font><I><Font
        html:Color="#000000">oo</Font></I><Font html:Color="#000000">n</Font></ss:Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:Height="19.5">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s161"><Data ss:Type="Number">322</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s162"><Data ss:Type="DateTime">2016-11-01T00:00:00.000</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s163"><Data ss:Type="Number">52</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s164"><ss:Data ss:Type="String"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><B><S><Font html:Size="14"
         html:Color="#548235">S</Font></S></B><Font html:Color="#000000">hou</Font><Font
       html:Color="#FF0000">t</Font><Font html:Color="#000000">er K</Font><Font
       html:Color="#C65911">res</Font><Font html:Color="#000000">t</Font></ss:Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
 </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call a template, the current node doesn't change. You need to work directly with your `myElement` parameter to achieve what you want. Instead of `@html:Color` use `$myElement/@html:Color`:

```
<xsl:attribute name="style">
    <xsl:if test="$myElement/@html:Color">color:<xsl:value-of select="$myElement/@html:Color"/>; </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$myElement/@html:Size">font-size:<xsl:value-of select="$myElement/@html:Size"/>pt; </xsl:if>
</xsl:attribute>
```

If you were using matching the current node would be the matched node, and your tests would be correct.

As your input structure matches your output structure, matching provides a simple way to generate your required output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
                xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
                xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"
                exclude-result-prefixes="x ss html"
                version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ss:Workbook/ss:Worksheet/ss:Table/ss:Row"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ss:Row">
        <tr><xsl:apply-templates select="ss:Cell"/></tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ss:Cell">
        <td><xsl:apply-templates select="ss:Data"/></td>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- lower case names for embedded html elements -->
    <xsl:template match="html:*">
        <xsl:element name="{lower-case(local-name())}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- turn html font tags into spans with style attributes -->
    <xsl:template match="html:Font">
        <span>
            <xsl:if test="@html:Color or @html:Size">
                <xsl:attribute name="style">
                    <xsl:if test="@html:Color">color: <xsl:value-of select="@html:Color"/>;</xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="@html:Size">font-size: <xsl:value-of select="@html:Size"/>pt;</xsl:if>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you much, That sends me in the right direction!